# Функция нормального распределения в PHP

Tags: php

Помогите получить функцию нормального распределения в PHP. Пробовал функцию **stats_cdf_normal**, но почему то не подключается модуль **stats**, так и не понял почему. А другие функции нормального распределения в PHP не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Функция находится в пакете PECL , см. документацию https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php. Я установил его в моей системе, и он, кажется, работает. Для установки смотрите https://www.php.net/manual/en/stats.installation.php. Если вы работаете в Windows, вам, возможно, придется собрать его из исходного кода.